# How do I write something that can be passed into Go's http.Server{ErrorLog}?

Tags: go

I'm trying to capture certain common errors that are filling up my logs and squelch them since they're not actionable.  Things like invalid TLS handshakes and autocert errors where no SNI information is provided.

I tried:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type filteringLogger struct {
    *log.Logger
}
```

... snip NoOp methods - full code: https://play.golang.com/p/pp36dpP3sH0 ...

```
func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        ErrorLog: &filteringLogger{},
    }

    err := server.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

but, of course, that didn't pass `go vet`:

```
cannot use &filteringLogger{} (value of type *filteringLogger) as *log.Logger value in struct literal
```

I know I can override the output Writer but that just deals in bytes.  My hope was to intercept `error`s and if they were of specific types I'd skip passing them along.

Comment: "capture certain common errors that are filling up my logs and squelch them since they're not actionable" I doubt that it's the best idea to just drop them.

Comment: What I ended up doing was to route the standard library's logging output through my own Writer that sends all messages to ZeroLog.  However, for a distinct set of patterns, it dials down the severity to Debug rather than Info.  This lets me continue to receive unexpected errors but to also quiet down all the hooligans rattling the knob on my door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log.Logger` is not an interface, it's a struct type, so you can't just create a wrapper around it and use it in the `http.Server` like you are trying to do. As far as I can tell, there isn't really a good way to do what you are looking for other than by creating a custom output sink that you pass in to a logger and then messing around with the bytes.

Comment: Aw, man.  That's really unfortunate.  I guess I can set the output to `io.Discard` and just not worry about it.